# Are the video memory and the GPU memory the same

Tags: memory

In Chrome task manager, there is a column called GPU memory. In GPU-z, I can see the memory size information of the video card. I suppose it is the video memory. Is it the same as GPU memory?

[image: GPU-z]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** that is the same as the GPU Memory.

The only exception to this is on some lower-end computers use a technique called [shared graphics memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_graphics_memory) in which the integrated graphics card uses some of the RAM as video memory. In the case of your non-integrated graphics card, this would *not* be the case.